# Process for building OpenStack packages?

Tags: package-management, compiling, openstack, packaging

I am trying to build OpenStack packages (swift and keytone from Mitaka's release) and all its dependencies for Ubuntu 16.04.

By exploring jobs like https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/Releases/view/Xenial/job/xenial_newton_keystone/ , the following steps can be concluded:

1. Git clone OpenStack source from github's /openstack/keystone project
2. Build tar using python setup.py sdist
3. Git clone OpenStack code from appropriate branch from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/keystone
4. Generate source package using debuild -S -sa -us -uc
5. Sign the packages using debsign
6. Generate debian package using sbuild

My confusion is with steps 1-3. Why is the tar generated with the source cloned from OpenStack's github project but in step 3 the source is then obtained from launchpad? Is this done to obtain the debian/ directory?

Is there any documented process on how to build OpenStack packages in Ubuntu?

Any help will be appreciated!